# jQuery conflicting with inline CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table generated from MySQLi using PHP, and for each row there's at least two `<a>` links which have their style set by `<style>` to hide if, for example, status is not 0.

Now, I have included jQuery Datatable (https://datatables.net/) and here's the problem: no matter if the status is 0 or not, the plugin mentioned above shows the links, even if the `!important` rule is specified.

I have used the jQuery `noConflict();` but it disabled the whole datatables plugin.

I tried changing the `<a>` links style by jQuery or removing attribute, but no luck.

The code which I use to hide/show elements (depending on the 'status') is:
`echo "<style>#approve$row[id] { visibility: hidden !important; };</style>";`

I expect the plugin to not have conflicts with the `<style>`, or at least find a solution  to specify the priorities (except the `!important`) so that the one specified in `php` is executed over the jQuery's one.

Interestingly enough, only the first row of the table is not affected, the rest others, are. See the image below:

[image: the first row shows expected result, and the second one actual one][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqQ2s.png)

Answer (score 0):

Define you css in a common stylesheet of your project or try it by remove !important .as it gives higher preference to implement.

Comment: Since I have to check from DB the status, I can't define the CSS in a common stylesheet. Also, it's the same whether has `!important` or not.